# can we have separate files to identify sObjects in Apex code

Tags: apex

Visual Force Page supports Model-View-Controller architecture in which we have separate controller files but `how can we identify models` for that controllers.

Sorry if my question is wrong as I am new to Apex code development I want to know whether we have different file names for models in Apex code.

**Update:**

Can I consider `.object` files as models in Apex Code?

Answer (score 1):

The Salesforce take on MVC is described in documents such as [An Introduction to Visualforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Visualforce).

Raw SObjects themselves are commonly used as the model because Visualforce can automatically leverage the SObject meta-data via tags like `apex:inputField` that present a field's label, the appropriate sort of editing widget and support "required" input.

You can also create your own Apex classes and use those as the model. There is no required naming or required class to extend or interface to implement but you could choose to apply any of those patterns yourself as a convention or convenience. (If the data is to be stored in the Salesforce database, SObjects still have to be used to do that.)